# After copying the SSAS cube and SSIS packages there is processing problem

Tags: ssis, ssas

After copying the SSAS cube and SSIS packages that run its recalculation in Analysis Services Processing Tasks, something strange happens. It doesn't matter whether a new SSIS is launched or an old one, the old cube is still recalculated not new one. Double checked the SSISDB connections and SSISDB configuration and are different in the new and old SSIS package. Cubes are also processed without any problems at the SSMS level. The cube IDs have also been changed so that the new SSIS package uses the connection to newSSASCubeID. Yet it somehow triggers oldSSASCubeID processing. Any tips?

Comment: I've had this problem if I keep the old cube on the server. Even if the old cube is renamed, somehow under the covers SSAS still holds onto the old cube. The only way I was able to resolve this was to drop the old cube completely. You can always take a backup of the old one in-case you need it, just don't keep the old cube in the SSAS DB. At least, that's been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I found the place where Task keeps the ID of the old cube.

In ProcessingCommands property there is generated XMLA with old IDs:

```
  <Process>
    <Object>
      <DatabaseID>OldDatabaseID</DatabaseID>
      <CubeID>OldCubeID</CubeID>
      <MeasureGroupID>SomeMeasureGroupID</MeasureGroupID>
    </Object>
    <Type>ProcessClear</Type>
    <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
  </Process>
```

I originally only replaced OldCubeID, but I should have also replaced OldDatabaseID.
So this solves the problem completely.